# How to Pair an Observable with State?

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive

I am learning Rx.Net, and I am building a scheduler that runs on numerous intervals.  The idea is that I have a collection of intervals and a collection of commands, and I tuple them together and subscribe to the merged result.  Each command is to be associated with its respective interval, and is to be executed on the interval (cadence) that is defined with its association.

While I am able to merge the intervals together, I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to pass in this command (state) to the subscription. 
 I did see the `Scan` function, but this looks to aggregate and not couple/tuple.  Here is my code:

```
var intervals = new[]
                {
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)
                };
var commands = new Action[]
                {
                    () => Console.WriteLine("30 Seconds!"),
                    () => Console.WriteLine("60 Seconds!"),
                    () => Console.WriteLine("90 Seconds!")
                };

intervals.Zip(commands, ValueTuple.Create)
         .Select(x => Observable.Interval(x.Item1)) // <-- Need magic here. :)
         .Merge()
         .Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        x.Item2(); // Broken, x is a long.
                    });
```

Is there a way in Rx to do what I am looking to achieve here?  Something like a `Scan` but isn't an accumulator, but rather a tupler (if that is a word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the action repeated at 30, 60, 90 second intervals:

```
intervals.Zip(commands, ValueTuple.Create)
         .Select(x => Observable.Interval(x.Item1).Select(_ => x))
         .Merge()
         .Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        x.Item2(); // Broken, x is a long.
                    });
```

If you just want the action to trigger once:

```
intervals.Zip(commands, ValueTuple.Create)
         .Select(x => Observable.Delay(Observable.Return(x), x.Item1)) 
         .Merge()
         .Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        x.Item2(); // Broken, x is a long.
                });
```

Comment: Woohoo!  That was exactly what I was looking for!  Super simple (and a bit obvious haha) to boot. Thank you @Shlomo!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go with a slightly different version for the query that you need.

Right now, the query part of your code (the bit up to and including the `.Merge()` only selects the command - and you are relying on the subscriber to execute the command. You're trusting a subscriber to execute the command for you. That might be the right logic in some circumstances, but not all.

My thinking is that when you subscribe to the observable you want to ensure that the command is run regardless of what the subscriber does. The subscriber should only react to the observable producing a value if it feels that it should.

Here's the code for this:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    intervals
        .Zip(commands, (Interval, Command) => new { Interval, Command })
        .Select(x =>
            Observable
                .Interval(x.Interval)
                .SelectMany(y =>
                    Observable
                        .Start(() => x.Command())))
        .Merge();
```

Whenever an observer subscribes, the command is ensured to run. The observer just can report that it's done so.

The most basic subscription is now just `IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();`. Simple.

Comment: This is another valuable take on this problem indeed, as I mentioned I am new to Rx and was not familiar with `Observable.Start` (or at least, in this context) and this is good to know about going forward.

Comment: @Mike-EEE - `Observable.Start` is just a way to run some code that produces an observable that completes when the code completes. It's the equivalent of `Task.Run` for TPL.